# Discord bot issues in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I think I am having some issue with intents in javascript. I am completely new to this and would appreciate any helpful resource material. I have found many programs online, but I am unable to get a lot of them to work due to what I am guessing is a lack of proper intents.

with using intent bits i was able to receive the message, but was not able to read it's contents. with the instructions below I am not able to receive or read messages even though I have guildmessages and messagecontents put into my intents. I know this isn't perfect, but my knowledge is related to what is online. Does anyone know why I am unable to receive or read messages with this program?
I also have all my privileged gateway intents checked in the developer page.

My JS

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
  ],
});
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message == "!hello") {
    message.channel.send("Hiya");
    console.log("message sent");
  }
  if (message.content.includes("!h")) {
    return message.reply("Hee");
  }
  console.log("message recieved");
});
```

Comment: just curious- have you considered asking for help on the [discord server](https://discord.gg/djs) or [github repo](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js)? If you have and decided against it- why? my gut says that people there are probably much more equipped to help you.

Comment: For future reference try making your title relative to a specific issue in bot making. Users already know you're dealing with an issue when you post anything to this site

Answer (score 1):

First issue:
you missed `.content`

```js
  if (message.content == "!hello") {
```

Second issue:
`"message"` is now `"messageCreate"`

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
```

Third issue:
You didn't login the bot

```js
client.login("your bot token")
```

Optional:

1. Go to [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)
2. Select your bot app and choose [Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pSyR.png)
3. Scroll down until you see [Privileged Gateway Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTb10.png), tick all of them

Comment: Thank you for your help, I purposefully didn’t show my bot login. I did forget to put in that I fixed the message.content problem, but I forgot the “messageCreate”.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. But, I managed to fix it. I am writing my code below with the instructions. I hope, it will be useful.

- Create a js file. Give it a name and write the code below. I will name it **"**bot.js**"**.

```
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Partials
} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages],
  partials: [Partials.Channel]
});
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', message => {

  if (message.content === 'ping') {

    message.channel.send('Pong!');

  }
});

client.login(config.token);
```

- Also, create a **"config.json"** file to put your token.

```
{
 "token": "write your token"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's actually `IntentsBitField`, not `GatewayIntetnsBits`. Example is:

```js
const client = new Client({
   intents: [
      IntetnsBitFiels.Flags.Guilds
   ]
})
```

And don't forget to login to your bot

Comment: I got IntentsBitField to work somewhat, but I am still unable to receive or send out a message using the bot

Comment: do you have an example you could share with me that you have gotten to work?